# I can't find SQLite in applications/library

Tags: database, xcode, sqlite

I can't find SQlite in applications/library. I've implemented the code to create the database. It's a small test,  basically it just adds a person's first name and last name to a table. I don't have to download it, do I? I'm using Xcode 4.6.

Comment: That isn't enough detail to answer your question.

Comment: saw this tutorial where the he runs the simulator and in the finder he does 
Macintosh>Application support>iphone simulator>name of the project>library and the SQlite database table pops up. 

I've tried it and it doesn't show Application support, iPhone simulator or SQL.I've written the exact same code as him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add usr/lib/sqlite_3.0.lib to the frameworks and #import sqlite3.h in your code.

If you need an example, see this link
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application_(Xcode_4)

If you've already done it, what is the error message you are receiving?